# Request.Url.AbsoluteUri and rewritten URL's

Tags: asp.net, .net, url-rewriting

I need to be able to get the URL as I see it in the browser i.e The rewritten one. For instance:

If my Url was `www.myurl.com/Test.html` and I then used `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`, the URL returned would be: `www.myurl.com/Default.aspx?Action=Test`

I need to be able to get back the exact rewritten URL.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, didn't realise you could do inline code tags.

Comment: Have you tried Request.RawUrl? I think that gives you the unmapped URL.

Comment: That provides enough for me to be able to build the url: i.e it returns /Test.html to which as it happens, is the bit I really need anyway. Can you make an answer post please so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Tchami:

Have you tried Request.RawUrl? I think that gives you the unmapped URL.

Will mark this as the answer when I am allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the URL so, that it includes the original URL as a querystring parameter.

For example: url="(.*)" to="http://newurl.com?original=$1".
(Note you'll still have to adjust the regex to work with URLs that contain a querystring.)